# Custom layout CollectionView can't scroll

Tags: ios, objective-c, uicollectionview

I followed the book **"Learning AVFoundation"** to create a video editor, the sample code use custom collectionview layout to show video and music track. Everything works fine. However, I can't horizontally scroll my UICollectionView. I checked content size is fine, it will increase after I add a clip. TouchEnable also checked, but no idea what's wrong here...
[My screenshot is like this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WuNiG.jpg)

Comment: Please post some code.

Answer (score 1):

Just answer my question here.
I made a silly mistake. Didn't notice that my layout add a **UIPanGestureRecognizer**, it will take care pan direction instead, so the view can't scroll even content size is right.
I think below code affect the scroll behavior. Just remove gesture first then another way to control drag and move cell behavior.

CGPoint location = [recognizer locationInView:self.collectionView];
    CGPoint translation = [recognizer translationInView:self.collectionView];
    self.panDirection = translation.x > 0 ? THPanDirectionRight : THPanDirectionLeft;